# JSON exception while calling getJSONObject

Tags: java, android, json, getjson

IN json object if we can found if data exist by jsonobj.has("element_name") by how can we check that data is jsonarray or json object, follow error gives error if only one events element found and throws JSONexception.

```
JsonObject jObj;
if (json.has("Events")) {
    try {
        JSONArray eventsArray = json.getJSONObject("Events");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        jObj = json.getJsonObject(""Events"")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you're trying to read an array using `getJSONObject` instead of `getJSONArray`?

If it's possible that the `Events` array doesn't always exist, you should be using the `optJSONArray` method.

If it's a different problem, you'd need to post some example JSON for the success and failure cases to make your question clearer.